# Java InputStream.read(byte[], int, int) method, how to block until the exact number of bytes has been read

Tags: java, inputstream

I'm writing a simple client/server network application that sends and receives **fixed size** messages through a TCP socket.

So far, I've been using the `getInputStream()` and `getOutputStream()` methods of the `Socket` class to get the streams and then call the `read(byte[] b, int off, int len)` method of the `InputStream` class to read 60 bytes each time (which is the size of a message).

Later on, I read the Javadoc for that method:

> public int read(byte[] b,
>          int off,
>          int len)
>            throws IOException
>
> Reads **up to** len bytes of data from the input stream into an array of
>   bytes. An attempt is made to read as many as len bytes, **but a smaller
>   number may be read**. The number of bytes actually read is returned as
>   an integer.

I was wondering if there's any Java "out-of-the-box" solution to block until **len** bytes have been read, waiting forever if necessary.

I can obviously create a simple loop but I feel like I'm reinventing the wheel. Can you suggest me a clean and Java-aware solution?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use `DataInputStream.readFully`.  Its [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readFully-byte:A-) directs the reader to the `DataInput` [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readFully-byte:A-) Javadocs, which state:

> Reads some bytes from an input stream and stores them into the buffer array `b`. The number of bytes read is equal to the length of `b`.

```
InputStream in = ...
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream( in );
byte[] array = ...

dis.readFully( array );
```

Comment: DataInputStream... An old but incredibly useful class. This seems to be the killer answer! :P

Comment: Man I forgot about this function thanks, saved me a ton of debug time!

Comment: The JavaDoc link is broken

Answer (score 2):

The simple loop is the way to go. Given the very small number of bytes you're exchanging, I guess it will need just one iteration to read everything, but if you want to make it correct, you have to loop.

Comment: It reminds me of old school unix socket programming. :) I was wondering if the InputStream coming from the Socket class actually belongs to a 'clever' class... Seems like I have to wrap the InputStream.

Comment: DataInputStream indeed has a readFully method (that I forgot about). Look at its implementation: all it does is a simple loop until enough bytes are read from its wrapped input stream.

Comment: I see. I prefer using Java API classes even for simple things because I need my code to be the more readable, portable and neat as possible.

Comment: Of course. You should use readFully. I just wanted to make you realize that it contained no magic: all it does is looping as you would have done.

Answer (score 0):

a simple for one-liner will do the trick

```
int toread = 60;
byte[] buff;
for(int index=0;index<toread;index+=in.read(buff,index,toread-index));
```

but most of the time the only reason less bytes would be read is when the stream ends or the bytes haven't all been flushed on the other side

Comment: I believe there is a subtle bug in that loop. What happens if `read` returns `-1` (if the stream is closed prematurely)? Would this loop then become an infinite loop?

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct version of ratchet freak's answer is this :

```
for (int index = 0; index < toRead && (read = inputStream.read(bytes, index, toRead-index))>0 ; index+= read);
```

it stops reading if read returns -1