# Android Socket - Memory Leak - Incoming message

Tags: java, android, performance, sockets, packet

first question here and I hope that you can help me :)

The code (below) is some code that was written a while back which listens for incoming packets on an open socket. The code works well and manages to listen to all incoming messages, however the problem seems to be with this function below. It seems like this code is always being run, which is causing it to use large amounts of CPU power and large amounts of RAM. I am unable to show much more code as there is lots of it. Just wondering if there is a better way of knowing that a packet has arrived. Here is the code:

**

```
{
    if (socket.getInputStream() != null)
    {
        if (socket.getInputStream().available() > 0)
        {
            int i = socket.getInputStream().available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[Global.c_iRxArraySize];
            socket.getInputStream().read(buffer);

            short[] converted = new short[Global.c_iRxArraySize];
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                converted[j] = (short) (buffer[j] & 0xff);
            }
            Global.sNoTransmittionRecievedTimeout = 0;

            p_DebugreceivedMessageSize = FindPacketSize(converted);
            p_DebugreceivedMessageCount = p_DebugreceivedMessageCount + 1;
            p_DebugreceivedMessageData = GetPacketContents(converted);

            Date date = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat p_DebugreceivedMessageTime = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a");
            DateReceivedData = p_DebugreceivedMessageTime.format(date);

            List<String> DataListReceived = new ArrayList<String>();
            DataListReceived.add(Arrays.toString(p_DebugreceivedMessageData));

            MobileRxProtocol(converted);
            Global.p_ReconnectionTimer = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The `read` method of `InputStream` does not guarantee you have actually read N bytes, if N was the size of the buffer. In fact it returns the number of bytes it has managed to read. This has nothing to do with your question but I think you should be aware of it. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131421/java-inputstream-readbyte-int-int-method-how-to-block-until-the-exact-num

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Global.c_iRxArraySize is of fixed size you could try to reuse buffer and converted, also you could try to reuse SimpleDateFormat, no need to create and destroy this for every call and the DataListReceived could be reused and cleaned in the end of this process.

Declare all this variables outside this scope and reuse then, I think that is the first step at least.

Comment: Thanks very much, will make a few changes, and will most likely remove the timestamp, It was added for debug reasons I believe, so can be easily removed.